# How does shuffle and batch work in tf.data.dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working on a large dataset with around 10million datapoints so I've decided to use tf.data.dataset api for fetching dataset.

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data))
train = train_dataset.shuffle(100000).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

I've few doubts which isn't clear from tensorflow docs. I hope someone can address them.

How does the shuffle work in my case? Because I have 10 million datapoints should I shuffle all 10 million (or) will 100k be enough? Will it have any performance impact choosing a large shuffle?

Will the batch is considered only from shuffled dataset (or) the original dataset?

Comment: I myself found tensorflow document inefficient in some cases,coming to `shuffle()` ,I think if you shuffle all the data points at once it will be store in buffer,so it is recommended not to shuffle all the data at once although not sure about the performance